# Problema com catch em conexão MySQL c#

Tags: c#, mysql, try-catch

Olá sou iniciante em programação e estou com problemas em conectar o MySQL no c#, onde o código não faz a verificação e vai para a ação catch. Segue o código:

```
conexaoDataSet = new DataSet();
            conexao = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=tcc; UID=root; PASSWORD=;");
            try
            {
                conexao.Open();
                MySqlCommand verifica = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CMS_pilots WHERE nome='" + txt_login.Text + "' and senha ='" + txt_senha.Text + "'", conexao);
                bool resultado = verifica.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
                if (resultado == true)
                {
                    conexao.Close();
                    adm f2 = new adm();
                    f2.Show(this);
                    Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login inválido!");
                    conexao.Close();
                }
            }
            //erro acontece a partir de aqui
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro de conexão com o banco de dados");
                conexao.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Nayanne, seja bem vinda ao SOpt. Para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma resposta, seria melhor você incluir o código ao invés da imagem.

Comment: Olá, recomendo que leia [esse](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) e [esse post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) na seção de ajuda sobre como formatar uma postagem aqui no SOpt.

Comment: No bloco do `catch`, mude a linha para `catch (Exception ex)`. E na mensagem, troque para `MessageBox.Show("Erro de conexão, detalhes: " + ex.Message);`. Isso irá lhe fornecer detalhes do que está acontecendo. Edite sua pergunta com o erro que lhe for retornado.

Answer (score 2):

Nayanne, seu código está correto, você não deve estar conseguindo se conectar ao banco, faça o seguinte teste:
 `try{
    conexao.Open();
 }
 catch{
    MessageBox.Show("Não estabeleceu conexão com o banco de dados");
 }`

Realmente não conseguiu se conectar?
 Verifique se você já tem instalado o  MySQL Connector NET
 Sua string de conexão se esta correta?
 A referencia foi feita? e foi referenciada da forma correta?

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

Verifique neste exemplo detalhado que mostra desde a modelagem do banco, e como estabelecer a conexão com o banco de dados.

http://www.macoratti.net/08/08/c_mysql1.htm